# Open sub menu to hover menu icon

Tags: css, reactjs, menu, submenu, side-menu

I want to open sub menu when i hovered on menu icon with css or javascript.

Strucutre

- Icon // hover on this to open sub menu
          Text
          
          //sub menu with addition layer on menu.

  - Text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Without seeing your html and css we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it would be helpful if you already have any code and secondly I would try rephrasing it as - "Open sub menu when hovering over menu icon".

To do this it would be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

</div>
```

You can check out this page on W3Schools in which the example was taken from: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp